# Does adding the 'piercing' tag to warhammers require further tweaks from the GM?

Tags: weapons, dungeon-world

Realistically speaking, [war hammers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hammer) were used specifically for breaking through armor:

> War hammers were developed as a consequence of the prevalence of surface-hardened steel surfacing of wrought iron armors of the late medieval battlefields during the fourteenth and fifteenth centuries.

In Dungeon World there is the *Piercing* weapon tag, it means specifically that:

> *n Piercing:* It goes right through armor. When you deal damage with n piercing, you subtract n from the enemy’s armor for that attack.

However, neither Warhammer nor Mace have *Piercing*. They have no difference from swords and axes, actually:

> **Short Sword, Axe, Warhammer, Mace;** *close, 8 coins, 1 weight*

As a DM, I want to add 1-2 *Piercing* to war hammers in my game. My concern is, there is only one weapon that actually has *Piercing* in the default equipment (a "dueling rapier", whatever it is). In terms of game balance, does adding *Piercing* tag to warhammers break anything, forcing GM to justify consequences accordingly (for instance, make warkahhers heavy and harder to wield), presumably adding more tags (like *Awkward*)?

By "balance" I mean that game should feel fair, and nobody steals the spotlight from any PC.

Sister question: [Does adding the 'precise' tag to daggers break anything?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153842/)

Answer (score 14):

### No, it doesn't break anything

Dungeon World, like the other *World games, does not depend on careful design-time balancing of classes/items/player moves etc. Balance in DW is a dynamic act that is continuously performed by the DM, by adjusting the hardness of the DM moves.

If some aspect of the game seems to be overshadowing others, all the DM has to do is choose harder moves when it misses. This raises the consequences, making it a tougher choice for the players to employ it.

#### Example: Plain Sword vs. Piercing Warhammer

> — I swing my sword around and stab the dark knight in the abdomen.
>   — *Ok, that's your plain Hack&Slash, please roll+STR*
>   — There goes a … 4! … ☠️⚡️
>   — *Hmm, the dark knight easily deflects your blow with his shield and brings your guard down. You notice his mace coming at your head from the left, what do you do?*

vs…

> — I swing my warhammer around and gore the dark knight in the abdomen.
>   — *Ok, that's your plain Hack&Slash, please roll+STR*
>   — There goes a … 4! … ☠️⚡️
>   — *Hmm, the dark knight easily catches your blow with his shield and brings your guard down. He catches the opportunity to bring his mace down on your helmet while your warhammer is firmly lodged in his shield. The world spins and your blood seeps into your eyes. Take 6 damage. It seems he's going to easily continue whacking at your head while you're stuck. What do you do?*

That's the GM move: *Show a downside of their equipment*. You have many more of those GM moves in your arsenal.

Note that you don't have to decide on using such an approach up front. You can slowly increase the stakes if a piercing warhammer seems to steal too much of the spotlight, and stop when it doesn't do that any more.

The balance of the game does not depend on equipment tags. It depends on how you respond to player moves.

Comment: *The balance of the game does not depend on equipment tags* — I'm pretty sure it does, a little. For instance, tags for the Signature Weapon move might become irrelevant.

Comment: *... does not depend on careful design-time balancing of classes/items/player moves etc. Balance in DW is a dynamic act that is continuously performed by the DM* —  if that was the case, all classes would be equal, including third-party ones; however, there are better and worse classes, more or less powerful. See the DW reddit for example https://www.reddit.com/r/DungeonWorld/comments/4m843f/arcane_duelist_question/

Comment: I think edgerunner's point is that Dungeon World gives the GM a lot of power to keep balance in their game even if things are not balanced on paper. Just by choosing hard vs soft moves, or the degree of hardness and softness, you can can keep things balanced, even if one piece of gear, or one playbook is theoretically OP. His example is that a piercing warhammer (which would be strictly better than a sword on paper) can have harsher downsides when you miss with it. Even gear that lets you hit more will be somewhat self-balancing over time, since characters gain much of their XP from failure.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks, your comment drives my point home

Comment: @enkryptor you are right that enriching a regular warhammer may run the risk of overshadowing a fighter's signature weapon. However, what I'm saying is, the DM is free to give the fighter more room when he misses with his signature warhammer than some other character who happened to get hold of the same weapon.

Comment: @Blckknght this answer describes the basics, how hoes DW work.Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. If the answer is "it doesn't break anything because mechanics in DW do not affect balance", this is simply not true. Mechanics do affect balance, you can see this comparing various third-party classes. The GM can vary things on the fly, but this is irrelevant for the question, it is just the way how the DW works.

Comment: "... your warhammer is firmly lodged in his shield. That's the GM move: Show a downside of their equipment." — you basically describes consequences of having the *Awkward* tag. Adding *Awkward* to warhammer on par with *Piercing* seems like a balancing solution. This is exactly what I asked. @Blckknght

Comment: @enkryptor you're right, tags do affect mechanical balance. Let's just say that mechanical balance isn't required to balance a *World game, and there isn't any extensive effort to balance the original content anyway. DW as written would not be balanced if it wasn't for the DM agenda and principles, and a few key rules like the XP on a miss rule

Comment: @enkryptor I would say there is a difference between always being awkward, and once in a great while failing oddly. I would find stilts or high heels to be very awkward, as I've never worn either. Sneakers aren't awkward, but very rarely one will slip off unintentionally, or the knot will come undone and I'll trip over the laces somehow. In this case, I'd say the spiked hammer is generally fine, but occasionally provides for a great story over ale in the Adventurer's Guild Hall.